# How to detect whether a file with spaces in its name exists?

Tags: string, bash, file-io, escaping

I am trying to detect whether a file named `semester1 (2013).csv` exists.

So far I have the following:

```
file="results/semester1\ (2013).csv"
if [ -f $file ]; then
  echo 'File exists.'
fi
```

Which produces the following error:

```
binary operator expected
```

What am I not escaping properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're escaping too much, but not quoting enough:

```
file="results/semester1 (2013).csv"
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  echo 'File exists.'
fi
```

If you don't quote `"$file"`, it gets expanded as two "words" in the test, and that fails. With the quotes, it gets passed whole to the test.